# How to mminimize the network traffic for pulling docker images for many hosts

Tags: docker, cache, docker-registry

I am looking for a mechanism to minimize docker pull traffic for a bunch of hosts which are provisioning the same docker image. I tried to use squid-cache but apparently it is no good as it has no mechanism to cache https.
I can not setup a local-registry as well as the remote registry is **not** docker hub and as the remote is a private registry no mediator-private registry can work in that scenario as well.
As the data being pulled is huge and repetitive, can someone suggest a method to help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Man in the middle the TLS connections with a proxy that will cache non Docker Hub requests. Requires pushing a CA certificate to all the Docker clients.

https://github.com/rpardini/docker-registry-proxy  claims to implement such a thing.

Comment: Thanks seems to be exactly what I am looking for with downside of CA injection though

Comment: MITM with a CA is how that hack works. The client should *not* use `--insecure-registry`, to force any malicious MITM to go through as much trouble to trust a bad cert.